# How to use "gf" on filenames containing spaces in gVim?

Tags: windows, vim, editor

In gVim if the cursor is over a filename (like "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim71\README.txt" ) which contains spaces then using 'gf' fails.

I found the [isfname](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27isfname%27) option but the documentation says one should avoid using spaces.

Is there I can make gVim open files under these circumstances ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select the text in visual mode, then do a `gf` on it.  That gets around the problem to some extent.

Comment: this works somewhat, but gF is even better when you have a fil/path:44 (followed by a line number. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Windows' "8dot3" filenames. I've tested it out in Windows 7 + GVIM succesfully.

Find out the short filename by using the /X flag in the CMD prompt. You want to CD to the parent folder to that which has spaces in it. I'm not sure how to get the whole path at once in "8dot3" form.

Typing "cd " and then dragging from the Explorer's address bar to the CMD window can be easier than typing out the path:

```
> cd "C:\Users\Fabrice\Documents"
> dir /X
```

Then use it in Vim, eg:

```
C:\Users\Fabrice\Documents\MYGAME~1\Skyrim\SkyrimPrefs.ini
```

If using a folder instead of a file name, the path appears properly expanded in the Netrw listing (:Ex file list).